# existence of lattice point in polytope

Tags: nt.number-theory, convex-polytopes, linear-programming, integer-programming

This question was probably asked before but here goes. I have a convex polytope given by $Ax\leq b$ for a specific integer matrix $A$ and integer vector $b$. I need a simple method/result on how to check existence of a lattice point inside this polytope. I realize that this is not a very precise request but any kind of input would be nice. I'm not sure if it matters but $A$ is a sparse matrix.

Comment: What precisely do you mean by the expression $Ax \leq b$?

Comment: This is integer programming (feasibility); NP-hard in general. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming

Comment: I doubt this would help (because computing the volume is difficult), but you may be interested in [Minkowski's lattice-point theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski's_theorem), which infers the existence of a lattice point from the volume.

Comment: Note that while the general problem is hard, it is often easy to solve specific instances, so if you tell us more about your problem, you might get more useful info.

Comment: @StefanKohl I mean I'm writing all inequalities defining the half spaces defining my polytope in matrix form

Comment: @Joseph. My polytope is not symmetric. In fact it's highly non symmetric. But this theorem is actually quite helpful. Is there something similar without the symmetry requirement?

Comment: @Abhinav. I just realized that a generic algorithm is probably too much to ask. Didn't realize though that it's NP hard. Thank you

Comment: @IgorRivin My polytope actually comes from representation theory and it's a variation of something called the hive polytope.

Comment: Without the symmetry requirement, a convex polytope can have arbitrarily large volume and no lattice point.

Comment: If your polytope IS the hive polytope, then http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9807160 provides a linear functional whose maximum on a hive polytope is always attained at an integer point, hence reducing the problem to linear programming. On the other hand, counting lattice points in the hive polytope is #P-complete http://www-igm.univ-mlv.fr/~fpsac/FPSAC06/SITE06/papers/01.pdf These polytopes have a lot of extra combinatorial structure coming from representation theory; you are better off describing what polytope you are working with and trying to approach the problem that way.